# C# FileStream long paths

Tags: c#

I'm having problem with my program, I'm creating backup system (Client send changed, created and renamed files to server and save them to server) but i'm not allowed save long paths and server crash (I can avoid crash with try/catch ofc) but I want save too long paths. How I can do it with FileStream?

My code:

```
user.CurrentFile.WriteStream = new FileStream(path + user.CurrentFile.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

You can find more about file paths and file names on [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is the paragraph you may be interested in:

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string < NUL>"
>   where "< NUL>" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

One of workaround is to use command line to assign a drive letter to one of your subfolders.